# Min_delta on callbacks function of Keras model seems to not take effect

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the following callbacks function on a Keras model and I initialize the minimum delta to 0.002, so based on the documentation of Tensorflow/Keras any improvement in the validation loss function less than 0.002 won't be counted for an improvement. However, this seems to not get implemented in my case.

callback function:

```py
def callback(folder_path, saved_model_name, patience_value, logdir, hparams):
    
    # Initialize parameters
    monitor_metric = 'val_loss'
    minimum_delta = 0.002
    patience_limit = patience_value
    verbose_value = 1
    mode_value = 'min'
    weights_fname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '{0}/{1}.h5'.format(folder_path, saved_model_name))
    
    # Initialize callbacks
    callbacks = [
        
        EarlyStopping(monitor=monitor_metric,
                      min_delta=minimum_delta,
                      patience=patience_limit,
                      verbose=verbose_value,
                      mode=mode_value,
                      restore_best_weights=True),

        ModelCheckpoint(filepath=weights_fname,
                        monitor=monitor_metric,
                        verbose=verbose_value,
                        save_best_only=True,
                        save_weights_only=True),
        
        tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir),
        
        hp.KerasCallback(logdir, hparams)
    ]
    
    return callbacks
```

The output per training epoch

[image]

You can see that in two highlighted epochs the validation loss improved from

- 0.02129 - 0.02015 = 0.00114 < 0.002 (although it was counted as an improvement)
- 0.01880 - 0.01803 = 0.00077 < 0.002 (also counted as an improvement in validation loss)

What is going wrong?

Please also check my colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FqQjjB2xFFQCiAqZacvVsl5SU0kcJwGd?usp=sharing), in order to check the whole training process

Answer (score 0):

Model Checkpoint callback saves the model anytime the validation loss decreases. It does not take into account the minimum delta you set for early stopping.

Comment: So what's the point of that argument in the Early Stopping method? I mean if it's there it should be taken into account

Comment: it is used for early stopping. If the validation loss fails to improve by at least the minimum you specified then depending on the level you set for the patience parameter say patience=2 then if it fails to improve for two consecutive epoch it will halt training.

Comment: I am NOT a big fan of early stopping. It is simply a crutch for not dealing with an over fitting problem or not using an adjustable learning rate. Over fitting is best handled by using dropout layers or keras regularizers.. Often the validation loss will fail to improve after a certain number of epochs. because the learning rate is to large. The callback

Comment: So Gerry you state that minimum delta is a baseline and if the validation loss goes below that line for example 0.002 the training is halted. So since 0.01803 > 0.002, that's why my training still goes on.

Comment: What did you set your patience value as? If I recall the validation loss delta must be smaller than the minimum value you set for patience number of CONSECUTIVE epochs.

Comment: my patience value is 10 epochs....The validation loss delta is in 0.00 range not 10, 20 or 20 but rather <<1 since my loss is between (0, 1)